# How to set a breakpoint in VirtualBox

Tags: debugging, operating-system, virtualbox, bare-metal

How do I sent a breakpoint at a particular address/line of code when debugging a guest OS in VirtualBox?  I found the debugger instructions (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#ts_debugger), but I don't see how to get the guest OS to stop executing at the point where I want to start examining the execution closely.

For more context: I am trying to debug a "toy" OS I'm writing.   I test the OS by running it in VirtualBox.  By following the instructions above, I can use the debug interface to examine the state of the guest OS/cpu after it halts (or enters an infinite loop); but, I don't see how to get the guest OS to stop/pause at a certain instruction.  There is a "stop" command; but, by the time I can open the debug command line and enter the command, the OS has already run to completion.  (My toy OS is not yet interactive.)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the address? (You may have to turn off hardware virtualization and use the `br` command to set a breakpoint). Real mode code is run in the recompiler entirely. So using `bp` vs `br` may depend on whether the breakpoint you want to set is in real or protected mode.

Comment: How do I get access to the debug command line before beginning to execute the guest OS?  (Or, in other words, how do I issue a bp or br command before the OS has passed the point that I want to break at?)

Comment: Did you run it from the command line with something like `virtualbox --debug-command-line --start-dbg --startvm path-to-vb/name-of-vb.vbox` where `path-to-vb` is the path where your virtual environment is and `name-of-vb` is the name of the configuration file with the `vbox` extension in that directory. You don't say what enviornment you are developing on (Windows/Linux) so I suggest the command line since it should work in both.

Comment: Yes.  When I do that, the OS immediately boots and begins executing.  It runs to completion before I get a chance to interact with the debugger.  Is there a way to "open" the VM and open the command line, but prevent booting/execution of guest OS until I request it?

Comment: In the command line you used did you have `--debug-command-line`? When I use both `--debug-command-line` and `--start-dbg` I get a debug console **before** the VM starts executing.

Comment: I see what I did wrong.  I do get the expected result this time.   But, I'm not sure what to do next.  When I do a core dump, I don't see the guest OS, I see what looks like the VM's BIOS.   (Memory location 0x7c00 is all 0's.)  When I run "g" (for "start") it tells me "g: error: The VM is already running".  When I run "t" (for "step") I get `error: VERR_SEM_OUT_OF_TURN:  When trying to single step VM 000000010d5f6000`  Are you aware of a document that discusses VM debugging at a higher level?  I get the feeling I'm missing some basics.

Comment: VirtualBox has some anomalies. One is the machine is put into a pause state at startup. `g` won't start it. If you are trying to debug real mode code load VirtualBox normally and change the settings for the VM you are trying to debug so that in General/System/Acceleration tab - the Intel VT-x/AMD-V is disabled. Then close VB, start the debug session. Then in the debug console command prompt type `br 0x7c00` to set a breakpoint. Inside the VM click the `machine` menu item and click `pause` to restart. At this point it should start running and break at the first instruction of bootloader.

Comment: I don't see an Intel VT-x/AMD-V option.   The only choice under System->Accereration is "Paravirtualization Interface:"  None, Default, Legacy, ...  I chose "none".  When I try to set the breakpoint, I get  `br: error: Failed to set REM breakpoint at 0000000000007c00: VERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`.  I am using version 5.1.22 on MacOS 10.11.6

Comment: What happens if you use `bp` instead of `br` . For this type of code I think you want to be running with paravirtualization off.

Comment: It runs to completion when I click `pause`.  (I did turn paravirtualization off.)

Comment: Interestingly, if I do a memory dump (.pgmphystofile) before clicking   pause, don't see my image.  It appears to be VirtualBox code and data only.  The memory at this point is all 0s up to 0x00c0000.

Comment: When you turn on a Virtual Machine the virtual BIOS hasn't started executing yet either. The virtual CPU is in default power on state. Because the virtual BIOS hasn't started running it hasn't attempted to find the bootable medium and hasn't tried to read the boot sector into memory. Because of that there is nothing loaded into memory at 0x7c00 etc.

Comment: That makes sense.  Any other ideas how to make the VM pause somewhere in my real mode code?  Is there a magic address in Virtual BIOS immediately before it jumps to the loaded boot sector?